# How do I unlock the Parity Ethereum Ethash prefunded account?

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, parity, ethash, chainspec

So i have my ethash node running with the following chainspec.json

```
    {
    "name": "Morden",
    "engine": {
            "Ethash": {
                    "params": {
                            "minimumDifficulty": "0x020000",
                            "difficultyBoundDivisor": "0x0800",
                            "durationLimit": "0x0a",
                            "blockReward": "0x4563918244F40000",
                            "homesteadTransition": "0x0"
                    }
            }
    },
    "params": {
            "accountStartNonce": "0x0100000",
            "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
            "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
            "networkID" : "0x42",
            "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x0400"
    },
    "genesis": {
            "seal": {
                    "ethereum": {
                            "nonce": "0x00006d6f7264656e",
                            "mixHash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578"
                    }
            },
            "difficulty": "0x20000",
            "author": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "timestamp": "0x00",
            "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "extraData": "0x",
            "gasLimit": "0x2fefd8"
    },
    "nodes": [
            "enode://c2328c3e7857106585dbb59b712ac2ab9443d4f0b55b77451fbf33c0dda58b882f0683c4c9222cbf8d1d6893e7f926d487630810202a2c75ec6dd996dbe84715@192.168.0.12:30303"
    ],
    "accounts": {
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } },
            "0x16a9dfd266e3229f05a2704c13bf2e16ea23e7c3": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376", "nonce": "1048576" }
    }
```

}

When i try to deploy a contract the password of 0x16a9dfd266e3229f05a2704c13bf2e16ea23e7c3 is required
what is my private key or how do i unlock this account?

Comment: You have to use an address that has been generated by yourself.

Comment: If you have the password, then you may follow [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/81970/16043) in order to retrieve the private key.